# My sub menu items are not responding to onClick event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, menu

I've created a menu with the following code

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" style="margin-left:500px">
   <LevelMenuItemStyles>
      <asp:MenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="10px" />
   </LevelMenuItemStyles>
   <LevelSubMenuStyles>
      <asp:SubMenuStyle CssClass="menuItem" />
   </LevelSubMenuStyles>
   <Items>
      <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/Home Clicked.jpg">
      </asp:MenuItem>
      <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/Categories Clicked.jpg" >
          <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/Category1.png"></asp:MenuItem>
          <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/Category2.png"></asp:MenuItem>
          <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/Category3.png"></asp:MenuItem>
      </asp:MenuItem>
      <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/itago picks clicked.jpg" >
      </asp:MenuItem>
      <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/Contact Clicked.jpg">
          <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/Contact1.png"></asp:MenuItem>
          <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/Contact2.png"></asp:MenuItem>
          <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/Images/Contact3.png"></asp:MenuItem>
      </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

I want the sub menu items to respond to an onClick event so I set following code up in the Page_load event

```
AddHandler Menu1.MenuItemClick, AddressOf Me.Menu_Click
```

Using the following method

```
Public Sub Menu_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub
```

When I run my code the Menu_Click event doesn't run when I click on a sub menu item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By clicking the sub menu if it is redirecting to a page, then use the following "NavigateUr"

```
 <asp:MenuItem Text="Option Prices" Value="Option Prices" NavigateUrl="~/hnewsdetails.aspx">
                                </asp:MenuItem>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it needs to run a method on the same page which just changes the view by hiding one panel and displaying another. Everything is handled on the same page.

Comment: use javascript instead